# Can I add database connections on a running application using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-boot

For example, I have a form where I going to put the user, password, port, etc of the database connection and when submit the connection to database is made and saved. Normally this is done in the application.properties before the application is running, but can I add it on runtime in an application? I this is possible, how can I do it?

Comment: And how is the application.properties file used?  Dig a little bit deeper.

Comment: Good question. If you’re going to use this through Spring jdbc, it will be too much difficult, however you can look for some way to wrap a pure connection using JDBC; normally define your connection string and pass it to jdbc manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be creating a `DatabaseConnection` entity with all necessary connection properties you mentioned (plus an `active: boolean` property). Use Spring Data to create a repository for that entity and create upper layer components. Serve a controller to your clients to CRUD on that entity.

A DatabaseConnectionService can provide the active JDBC connection to other components to make queries/updates.

Answer (score 1):

I have face similar situation in one of my project, using spring-jdbc it will be difficult to write the code and maintain. You can use normal jdbc to get the specified connection object using the connection parameters.

```
package com;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

@Component
public class DB2Connection {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DB2Connection.class); 

private static String DRIVER_NAME;

private static String VALID_QUERY;

@Value("${db.valid-query}")
public void setValidQuery(String query){
    VALID_QUERY = query;
}

@Value("${db.driverName}")
public void setDriverName(String driverName){
    DRIVER_NAME = driverName;
}

/**
 *  Getting the Database connection
 *  @param  url             url of the database
 *  @param  userName        username of the db
 *  @param  password        password of the db
 *  @return Connection      returns DB Connection object 
 * */
public static Connection getConnection(final String url, final String userName, final String password){

    logger.info("Getting DB Connection...");

    Assert.notNull(url, "Database URL can't be null");
    Assert.notNull(userName, "Database username can't be null");
    Assert.notNull(password, "Database password can't be null");

    Connection con = null;
    try{
        Class.forName(DRIVER_NAME);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);

        // testing for the valid connection
        if(testConnection(con)){
            logger.info("Valid DB Connection # Connection Tested...");
        }else{
            logger.info("In-Valid DB Connection...");
        }
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException cla){
        logger.error("Class Not found exception..."+ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(cla));
    }catch(SQLException sqe){
        logger.error("SQL Exception..."+ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(sqe));
    }catch(Exception exe){
        logger.error("Exception occured while making DB Connection..."+ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(exe));
    }
    return con;
}


/**
 *  Closing the java.sql.Connection class object 
 *  
 *  @param  con     Connection object which need to be closed
 *  
 * */
public static void close(Connection con){

    logger.info("Closing the connection object...");
    try {
        if(con != null ){
            con.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error("Exception occured while closing DBConnection..."+ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
    }
}

/**
 * This method will test connection if proper or not
 * @param   con     Connection object which need to be checked
 * @return  flag    true if connection is fine, false in case of connection is wrong
 * */
public static synchronized boolean testConnection(Connection con){

    boolean flag = false;
    logger.info("Testing the connection before providing to another process...");
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try{
        stmt= con.createStatement();

        // running the query for validation of the database
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(VALID_QUERY);
        while(rs.next()){
            // if we get Timestamp as return type - valid query is successfully run in the database
            Timestamp t = rs.getTimestamp(1);
            if( t != null){
                flag =true;
            }
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        logger.error("SQL Exception error..."+ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
    }finally{
        if(rs != null){
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Error in closing Result Set"+ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            }
        }if( stmt != null){
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error("Error in closing Statement"+ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            }
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

}

Define values of db.valid-query and db.driverName in application.properties file.
Call the getConnection() to fetch the connection object.

Also you can create your own custom actuator which can show you all the current connection objects that are being currently being live in the application. Extra code needed for maintaining the current object DB Connection object.

Comment: can you give me examples of the db.valid_query and db.driverName values that I have to put in the application.properties?

Comment: In case i am using DB2 as database, my application.properties will be like -# Check query for DB Connection
db.valid-query = SELECT CURRENT TIMESTAMP FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
db.driverName = com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver, Your db.valid-query and db.driverName will be change according to databases

Comment: But, although you had written the query in application.properties, you can still take queries from the database and change the used query?

Comment: the query in the application files is only for checking the database connection is valid or not, once you validate the connection object used the same connection and run the query using the Statement object.Connection con = DB2Connection.getConnection(dbDetails.getHostName(), dbDetails.getUserName(), password);Statement stmt=con.createStatement();ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("Select * from table_name");